# Stretching a Sprite

Tags: sprite, monogame

First post, first year programmer so go easy please.

When drawing a sprite in monogame, does anybody know how to make it stretch into the full screen?

For example I have my start screen appear but it doesnt stretch into the full screen (cause i have my window maximized when it opens). I've got "spriteBatch.Draw(startScreen, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White);"

the null represents the rectangle property. does anybdoy know a word to replace null so that will stretch it?

This is in my load content for the texture:

```
startScreen = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/startGameSplash");
```

Then this is where I call it in my Draw Method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            switch (gameState)
            { 
                case GameState.StartScreen:
                    //draw the start screen
                    spriteBatch.Begin();
                    spriteBatch.Draw(startScreen, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White);
                    //Drawing each rocket with another foreach
                    spriteBatch.End();
                    break;

                case GameState.Running:
                    spriteBatch.Begin();
                    tank.Draw(spriteBatch);

                    foreach (BaseRocket shot in rocket) {
                        shot.Draw(spriteBatch);
                    }
                    spriteBatch.End();
                    break;

                case GameState.EndScreen:
                    spriteBatch.Begin();
                    spriteBatch.Draw(endScreen, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White);
                    spriteBatch.End();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
            base.Draw(gameTime);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show more codes ?

Comment: Done, do you need more?

Comment: fine for now. If you read the documentation / [source code](https://github.com/ManojLakshan/monogame/blob/master/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs) of `SpriteBatch` class of monogame, you will see this: `public void Draw (Texture2D texture, Rectangle rectangle, Color color)`, which 2nd parameter is the size of the sprite. Assign the screen size rectangle to the parameter, and your sprite should fill the screen.

Comment: Got it to work thank you. I used spriteBatch.Draw(startScreen, new Rectangle(0,0,GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height), Color.White);

Comment: good to know the code is working now. i formatted the comment into answer below. please accept it if you found it useful, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From the [source code](https://github.com/ManojLakshan/monogame/blob/master/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs) / documentation of `SpriteBatch` class of MonoGame, there is a `Draw` function which accepts size as 2nd parameter:

```
public void Draw (Texture2D texture, Rectangle rectangle, Color color)
```

Assign the screen size rectangle to the parameter, and your sprite should fill the screen.